# No coach offered to Colorado Springs on American Airlines?

Tags: air-travel, american-airlines

I am trying to get an American flight to Colorado Springs and they are not showing any coach/economy seats, just Choice, Choice Plus, Choice Essential and First Class for about the same amount of money. Weirdly, it says "lowest fare $380" but none of the flights have that fare. Is the interface hiding the coach options?

Comment: Is it possible they've simply sold out of cheap seats?

Comment: are you trying to buy a one-way ticket? sometimes the cheaper seats are just not available for one-ways

Comment: Its round trip.

Comment: Call them and find out.

Comment: Also, check on some aggregators' websites, such as expedia or travelocity.  Sometimes they may have cheaper tickets.  This happened to me only last week, whereby cheapest tickets from London to Moscow on Aeroflot were about £300 if bought directly from Aeroflot.  Yet I bought tickets for the same flights on Expedia for £240 - 20% cheaper.  Aeroflot advertised £240 as the cheapest fare, but was showing it as sold out.

Comment: Aren't Choice, Choice Plus, and Choice Essential just names for [different economy fares](https://www.aa.com/i18n/utility/bundles.jsp)?

Comment: @ZachLipton Well, they were all very expensive and refundable, so I'll say no. In fact, of the choices, First Class was actually the cheapest option.

Comment: @LemuelGulliver They are coach fares with flexibility. The cheaper first class option will not have any flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I called them and from what I could gather from the Indienglish there may be an anomaly with the reservation web site and temporarily the Economy fares are being updated and therefore not appearing. The advice of the agent was to wait for several hours and try later.